# Internationalization with Angular 4

Tags: angular, internationalization, multilingual

I need to Add multiple language support for my Angular 4 Application.I need to know the best approach to achieve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **[ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core)** which is the standard library for internationalization in Angular 2+

You can import the library and create a set of json files which contains the translations and put it inside the assets folder.

Then you can refer it in the HTML. say for example.

**`en.json`** has,

```
"guest.first-name": "first Name",
```

where first one is the key and second is the value to be displayed .
and you can refer in the html as,

```
  <input  [label]="'guest.first-name' | translate" type="text" name="form_name" [(ngModel)]="firstName" required="required" ></input>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **ngx-translate** library that I used it and it is very useful for internationalization for Angular.Also I advice you about Angular, you should check **jhipster** project and then you can learn more advance and detail topics about Angular 4 and Spring Boot.It is very useful project and also you can create Angular and Spring Boot project rapidly...

Comment: Can you explain more about why these are good projects? Just the name of a library isn't always great context.

Comment: If you develop a project using Jhipster, you can understand that why jhipster project is good for developing.Because you can use most of library together via Jhipster.Also you can only check Jhipster project for checking which library or framework is popular now on the world

Answer (score 2):

if you use angular-cli to create newApp it has a good infrastructure for translate, that use ngx-translate. and for translate your text use pipe: translate like:

```
<span>{{ text | translate }}</span>
```

translate files exist on the /src/assets/i18n/langCode.json (forEx: en.json). and an initializing require in the main layout constructor

```
constructor(public translate: TranslateService, zone: NgZone) {
  translate.use('en');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do also a simple thing by making various files such as en.json etc. consisting of various lables such as

**en.json**

```
{

 lbl_name1: "Lable Name 1",
 lbl_name2: "Lable Name 2"

}
```

Now do a thing write a mechanism which will read the file,for Angular 6 we can use http client in an your **abc.ts** file & put the data into a session storage

```
    public languageVar: any = [];
    //Http Client can be used and you can pass the file name at runtime also, I have 
    passed it statically

    this.httpClientObj.get(en.json).suscribe({
    data=> {
           //setting into session for further use into app
           window.localstorage.setItem('langLables',JSON.stringify(data));

           //setting into the variable declared above
           this.languageVar = JSON.parse(window.getItem('langLables'));
       },
    error=>{
           alert("File not found"); 
      }
    }
);
```

Now suppose you have an html file, **abc.html**, by using one-way binding

```
<h1>{{languageVar.lbl_name1}}</h1>
<p>{{languageVar.lbl_name2}}</p>
```