# How to implement localisation in Angular 4

Tags: angular, localization

I read about the Angular and i18n template translation in the official Angular website. (https://angular.io/guide/i18n). But here, they have mentioned to deploy seperate version of application for each supported language. I am having more than 8 languages so it is not faesible to deploy many applications based on language. How should I proceed? Shall I use external libraries like **ngx-translate External library** or **angular-l10n** External library. My Gut feeling is to use angular-l10n External library. Expecting some heads up on this. Thanks

Comment: actually you dont have to deploy separate version if you are using ngx-translate. check this answer.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45604320/internationalization-with-angular-4

Comment: But this comparison makes me feel that angular-I10n library is better. https://github.com/robisim74/angular-l10n . Not quite sure though

Comment: i have tried the same! the above library is good if you are doing your own implementation using nodejs