# angular 2 tagCloud module

Tags: angular, angular2-template

i need a angular2 module (typescript) for show TagCloud with Diagonal Text & multiLanguage support (English / persian / arabic) & have responsive behavioral.

anyone can help me. with a sample code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45604320/internationalization-with-angular-4

Answer (score 1):

Here Have a look at this . Recently used it in one of my projects.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-tag-cloud-module