# pipes or directives for angular 2 translation?

Tags: angularjs, translation, angular-directive, angular-pipe

i am looking for a option to write my own  translation which replace the translated text, i want to know what would be better to use Pipes or Directives in terms of performance and all, because the number of components it will added is big.

so does using the massive amount of directives or pipes has any cons ?

Answer (score 0):

With angular,The pipe is quite easy to implement, as you already have our translation service in place. The only thing we have to do now, is call the translate method of the service.

Look at the following **[`question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45604320/internationalization-with-angular-4)** to get more idea on it.

Comment: i dont want to use ngx-translate library because they are using impure pipe.

Comment: if you are not using that, its going to be bit difficult, anyhow pipe is the best option to go